# Replace and delete with Regular expression?

Tags: c#, parsing

```
if (Result.Contains("http://"))
{
  string pattern = @"(http://)";
  theend = Result.Substring(Result.IndexOf("http://"));
  Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
  string replacement = "<a href="+theend+">"+theend+"</a> ";
  Result = rgx.Replace(Result, replacement);
}
```

The result is normal link (a href) and after that there is a string http://. How do I get only a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear exactly what are you trying to do. how does the input `Result` looks like.
if `Result` only contains the URL then just change:

```
Result = rgx.Replace(Result, replacement);
```

to

```
Result = replacement;
```

### Update:

Anyway, You can use this function:

```
private string ConvertUrlsToLinks(string msg) {
        string regex = @"((www\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+\:\/\/)[&#95;.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9\/&#95;:@=.+?,##%&~-]*[^.|\'|\# |!|\(|?|,| |>|<|;|\)])";
        Regex r = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        return r.Replace(msg, "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>").Replace("href=\"www", "href=\"http://www");
    }
```

Comment: Result is a string which may contain a link. I take that link (theend) and I want to replace all link with tag (a href) - to make html.

Comment: Can it contain more text after the link? can there be more than one link in it?

Comment: Yes, I use IndexOf to find link in the string. Yes, can contain more links, but in Replace i have optinon (int) how many string to replace.

Comment: Updated my answer with a generic solution. adopted from here: http://rickyrosario.com/blog/converting-a-url-into-a-link-in-csharp-using-regular-expressions/